# How to control an LED light by the output of a matlab program?

Tags: microcontroller, led, matlab

In my project, I'm designing the software to control a door using fingerprints, so I have 2 possible outputs: 1-door open, 2-door not open.

I need to change this output to an LED as an example (red when the door is closed, and green when the door is open). My program uses the Matlab language. How can I control an LED with the output using Matlab?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you using a micro controller and you want to program it?

Comment: seriously I Don't know If I need to micro controller or not, because I didn't understand in control part,  but I think I need it .
so what you think .

Comment: Are you designing this thing from scratch? Well if I were you I would bought some kind of fingerprints scanner, a development board of some sort and a led but this is in general because I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I see is to use a microcontroller with USB and then write MATLAB code to interface to the microcontroller.

Or the microcontroller's UART + an USB/UART IC and then use [MATLAB's serial port support](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.html).

Then you can drive pretty much anything connected to the microcontroller.